# Writing a parametric function as a Gaussian process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Given a random function with parametric form, how do we know if it can be described as a GP? For example, let $$f(t) = t^2 + X$$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Then $f(t)$ is a random function, where each realization has a normal distribution: $f(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(t^2, 1)$. I know that the marginal being Gaussian doesn't imply the joint being Gaussian, so it's not clear to me how to describe the distribution of $f$. If it's not a GP, then how could we describe the (joint) distribution?

The more specific case I'm thinking about is of the form
$$ F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$$ where $f_i(x)$ are iid from some distribution over functions. Each realization is also asymptotically normal but the central limit theorem, so I was thinking the above case would shed insight here.

Comment: By definition a Gaussian process has all finite dimensional distributions jointly Gaussian. This will not have that property, because a 2-time distribution is not jointly Gaussian (it's a degenerate 2D Gaussian with singular covariance matrix).

Comment: Ah the singular covariance matrix seems obvious now, thanks! What do you mean by 2-time? And is it possible for _some_ parametric function to be a GP? (Say, if all the parameters are gaussian)

Comment: I meant like the joint distribution of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$, which are perfectly correlated. Not sure what you mean by a parametric function necessarily.

Comment: Gotcha! By parametric function I mean some function that has a fixed form in terms of a variable, like for example $X^2+2$ (where $X$ could be an r.v.)

Comment: You mean a deterministic function of a finite number of Gaussians and time? No, that process will never be Gaussian; once you take a time sample from more time points than there are Gaussians, the covariance will be singular again.

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense now you say it like that... so could the above sum $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)$ be a GP as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and with x Gaussian? Thanks a lot, by the way

Comment: You mean like $F_t=\sum_{i \leq t} X_i$ (in discrete time) where $X_i$ are not-perfectly-correlated Gaussians? Sure, that can be a GP.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help (on several of my questions already!) Will definitely have more coming :D